# "Internal" in java native memory tracking output

Tags: java, memory-management

The resident size of my application seems to be growing. Native memory tracking shows "Internal" as the one taking unaccounted memory. What is stored in "internal"? [EDIT start] Any parameters to cap its usage? [EDIT end]

```
Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=31738149KB, committed=31345701KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=23068672KB, committed=23068672KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=23068672KB, committed=23068672KB) 

-                     Class (reserved=328745KB, committed=77737KB)
                            (classes #12946)
                            (malloc=3113KB #51815) 
                            (mmap: reserved=325632KB, committed=74624KB) 

-                    Thread (reserved=81139KB, committed=81139KB)
                            (thread #136)
                            (stack: reserved=79900KB, committed=79900KB)
                            (malloc=441KB #691) 
                            (arena=797KB #270)

-                      Code (reserved=218074KB, committed=76634KB)
                            (malloc=10074KB #12601) 
                            (mmap: reserved=208000KB, committed=66560KB) 

-                        GC (reserved=177074KB, committed=177074KB)
                            (malloc=127914KB #2258) 
                            (mmap: reserved=49160KB, committed=49160KB) 

-                  Compiler (reserved=549KB, committed=549KB)
                            (malloc=419KB #931) 
                            (arena=131KB #3)

-                  Internal (reserved=7590518KB, committed=7590518KB)
                            (malloc=7590486KB #12185456) 
                            (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB) 

-                    Symbol (reserved=13995KB, committed=13995KB)
                            (malloc=10535KB #104601) 
                            (arena=3460KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=193128KB, committed=193128KB)
                            (malloc=19KB #212) 
                            (tracking overhead=193109KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=200KB, committed=200KB)
                            (malloc=200KB) 

-                   Unknown (reserved=66056KB, committed=66056KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=66056KB, committed=66056KB)
```

Answer (score 2):

Documented, but not easily searchable -

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr022.html#BABHIFJC

Comment: Hey. Were you able to fix the issue? I am facing a similar issue but don't actually know how to debug the internal category of the Native Memory. Can you share the debugging steps or any resources ?